# How many are they, how much do you owe them?

Tags: mathematics, construction

Let's suppose you want to build a house.

To do this, you're going to need people to help build the house. Specifically, you're going to need *contractors*, *engineers*, and *construction workers*.

After weeks of work, they finally finish building the house, and now you owe them a total of $\$85000$.

Given the following data:

1- The number of all employees = 100

2- Each engineer's wage equals $0.2$ times that of a contractor, and each worker's wage equals $0.1$ times that of an engineer.

3-  Each contractor's wage = $8500.

How many *contractors*, *engineers*, and *construction workers* do you need, and how many dollars will each of them earn if the wages total to $\$85000$ ?

Comment: I believe we need to know how many of each type of worker there is. Otherwise, there is an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: @RobertS. The solution is one , it just needs a lucky guess as a key.

Comment: hi @benasfan I've clarified your question a bit, since you requested so. I'm pretty sure that I haven't changed the meaning of your question, but if I have, you may revert it back to your original.

Comment: I’m voting to close this because of the multiple answers identified by dr jimbob’s answer below. There needs to be more definition to identify one solution, and ought not to rely on “a lucky guess” as Ben keeps mentioning.

Comment: @El-Guest The name of the game is (Puzzling) that's why i posted it here rather than in the mathematical site. It took me hours to make this question. If i give you even a small hint, then no value to the whole question as a puzzle because the answer will be there immediately. I keep mentioning (guessing) to indicate that there is something called try and error analysis. I hope the idea is clear now.

Comment: @benasfan I understand that, but trial and error analysis, in my opinion, is not appropriate. Unless there’s a clever trick hidden in the puzzle that yields a unique solution, it’s inappropriate to ask puzzlers to guess answers repeatedly until they find the one that you deem to be correct, if the only reason why it is correct is because you deem it to be so.

Comment: @El-Guest Any solution that leads to 85000 is correct. That's a unique advantage of calculations, different ways , same answer. All am asking is how to get $85000 out of these variables. Add to that, for example, you can increase the number of workers to the double, then each one's wage is reduced to half, yes that's possible, you have the right to do that, which means the lots of workers you hire, the less money each one earns , and vice versa, however the total amount of money you owe them remains the same. So don't worry about the answer, I assure you it is one and only one which is 85000.

Comment: @benasfan As you can see in dr jimbob's answer, there are at least two solutions, even when we try to get minimum number of employees and assuming whole numbers for the wages. Neither of these assumptions are in your question. We could be missing some clues which are not made explicit in your question, but if that's the case, then perhaps the question is not very well defined. Perhaps you can comment on the correctness of dr jimbob's answer?

Comment: @benasfan That’s exactly my point — 85000 isn’t the solution, it’s one of the constraints that you’ve posed in your puzzle. You cannot expect people to post every single combination of workers and wages which gets to 85000. And if that is what you’re looking for, dr jimbob has provided you with an equation that represents all of them.

Comment: @benasfan I'm just saying, but this question has a lot of answers so, you need to specify some things in the question. Questions with various answers shows that it is too broad and they are generally frowned upon :D

Comment: @KevinL I edited it , read it again , many data were given. now you can easily answer it.

Comment: @El-Guest it has been edited by giving more details. And again, the answer is 85000, no change. Now answer it using the same formula of dr jimbob.

Comment: Voting to reopen, but I will vote to close again because this is a mathematics problem as opposed to a mathematical puzzle.

Comment: Agreed, @boboquack.

Comment: @boboquack Maybe I should have read the help center in the first place to know how to ask and where to put the question. The question was edited with all needed details, and dr jimbob's answer is correct. but you suggusted that it shouldn't be asked here. So Next time when I ask something, I'll make sure to give all necessary details.    Sorry and thank you gentle men, all of you ....^_^.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem was edited to be solvable with one solution. However, there may be references in the discussion to my old answer (see edits) when there weren't the constraints 100 total employees or Contractor wage = $8500.  We can now easily calculate the salaries from your information:

> Contractor = \$8500 = 50w
>  Engineer = .2 Contractor = .2*\$8500 = \$1700 = 10w
>  w = Worker = .1 Engineer = .1*\$1700 = \$170

We also now have two other equations, labeling $A$, $B$, $C$ as the number of workers, engineers, and contractors, respectively:

> $ A + B + C = 100$
>  $(A + 10 B + 50 C) \times \$170 = \$85000$

Solving the equations:

> $A + 10 B + 50 C = 500$  (divide both sides by \$170)
>  $A + B + C = 100$
>  $9B + 49C = 400$  (subtract equations above to cancel out A)

Looking for solutions with positive integer B and C,

> we can calculate both sides modulo 9 to eliminate the 9*B term:
>
>  $9B + 49C \equiv 400 \mod 9$
>  $49 C \equiv 400 \mod 9$    (9B disappears when B is an integer mod 9)
>  $4 C \equiv 4 \mod 9$       (49 mod 9 = 4; 400 mod 9 = 4)
>  $C \equiv 1 \mod 9$
>   Thus $C = 1 + 9k$ for some integer $k$, and it must be $k=0$ (as other integer values of k will make either $C$ or $B$ negative).
>  Then we have $B = (400 - 49)/9 = 351/9 = 39$.
>  Finally using $A + B + C = 100$, we see that $A = 100 - B - C = 60$

Hence, our solution has:

> 1 contractor earning \$8500, 39 engineers earning \$66,300 total (\$1700 each), and 60 workers earning $10,200 total (\$170 each).

Comment: I edited the question. now you don't need long time of trials. Though, I made the question, I had spent long time misleaded between lots of probabilities before i could construct it.

Answer (score 3):

Unless we specify at least a ratio of employees or something, this could be one of the answers.

> Contractor will make 50(5X10) times more money than the worker and that an engineer will make 10 times more money than the worker.
>  Set the salary of a worker to 1 dollar and hire 84940 workers, 1 engineer(10) and 1 contractor(50) for a total of 85000.

Comment: Good start, but with this amout of workers, we would make an invasion to a neighbouring country, not building a house.

Comment: @benasfan is the goal then to minimize the number of workers used? This solution is valid for the question as it is currently written.

Comment: @benasfan you’d also need to set at least some of the costs, because otherwise I say one worker earns $85k and all I need is one of him.

Comment: @El-Guest yes, exactly, the number should be less.